# Delphi TDBGrid selected row get value

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid, getvalue

I would like to retrieve a value from a TDBGrid the selected row, how can I do?

```
procedure TForm7.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      i, j: Integer;
      s: string;
    begin
      if DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count>0 then
        with DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet do
          for i:=0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 do
          begin
            GotoBookmark(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);
            for j := 0 to FieldCount-1 do
            begin
              if (j>0) then s:=s+', ';
              s := s + FindField(Fields.Fields[j].FieldName).AsString;
            end;
            Listbox1.Items.Add(s);
            s:= '';
          end;
    end;
```

Comment: What is your question?  There is one obvious problem with the code in your q, namely that you do not explicitly initialise your variable `s` for each selected row: add `s := '';`  after the `GotoBookmark...` line.

Answer (score 8):

The code below fixes a few problems with yours.

The main problems were the fact that you weren't correctly initialising `s` and your way of getting the fields for the selected row(s) was flawed.

The calls to `DataSet.Disable/EnableControls` and `ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` are to speed the process up.

Also, avoid the `with` construct like the plague.  As you can see, my use of a local `DataSet` variable instead involves minimal extra typing and avoids all sorts of accidental problems that can arise when you use `with`.

```
procedure TForm1.GetSelected;
var
  i,
  J : Integer;
  s : String;
  DataSet : TDataSet;
begin
  if DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count>0 then begin
    DataSet := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet;
   //  with DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet do
   try
     ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
     DataSet.DisableControls;
     for i:=0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 do
      begin
        DataSet.GotoBookmark(Pointer(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]));
        s := '';
        for j := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
        begin
          if (j>0) then s:=s+', ';
          s := s + DataSet.Fields[j].AsString;
          //s := s + FindField(Fields.Fields[j].FieldName).AsString;
        end;
        Listbox1.Items.Add(s);
        //s:= '';
      end;
    finally
      DataSet.EnableControls;
      ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Update: **

You can set the current grid row as selected like this

```
DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
```

**Update #2**

The grid's selected rows are stored in a `TBookmarkList` named `SelectedRow`.  To clear the current selections, all you need do is to call its `Clear` method, like so:

```
procedure TForm1.btnClearSelectedClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Clear;
end;
```

Equally, if you want to clear your ListBox, you just call its `Clear` method, as in:

```
procedure TForm1.btnClearListBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Clear;
end;
```

If you are having trouble getting my code to work, try this:

1. In the Object Inspector, set the DBGrid Options property `dgMultiSelect` to True.
2. Place a button on your form and in its `OnClick` handler call `GetSelected`.

Compile and run.  Click a row in the grid and then the button.  Nothing happens.  The reason is that clicking the button moves focus away from the DBGrid, so that as far as it is concerned, none of its rows is selected.  Then try step 3.

3. Run the app again.  This time press and hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while you click the grid then the button.  This time the selected row appears in the ListBox.  With the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button still down, click another row in the grid, then the button.  This time, both rows are added to the ListBox.

Comment: It does not work, unfortunately there is no row selected, but there is some property of which must be activated to select a row?

Comment: It does work.  See the update for how to select the current grid row.

Comment: but this istruction:  if DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count>0 then begin, does not find rows selected .

Comment: Then you are not using the code I posted.  Try this:  paste `  DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;` in as the first line of my `GetSelected` routine, then single-step through it in the debugger.

Comment: Work fine but only for one time. i need to reset maby? thank's very mutch

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean "by only for one time".  How does it "not work" after that?

Comment: simply put in the first time takes the data, then when we select another different line, the data of the first selection with the second are added together

Comment: we need a reset for bookmard, becose with instruction 's:=' '; don't resolve my problem

Comment: Ah, ok - see my **Update #2**.

Comment: what? i don't understand

Comment: Look, when you call my GetSelected method, it lists the records which are currently selected in the grid.  You said "then when we select another different line, the data of the first selection with the second are added together".  If you want the grid to permit **only** one record to be selected at a time, set the grid's `dgMultiSelect` to false.  If you want to allow more than one row to be selected at a time, set dgMultiSelect to true, and then when you want to clear the existing selections, call `DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Clear`.  You follow now?

Comment: Btw, please feel free to  "accept" this answer by clicking the green tick at its top left.

Comment: If you are with Delphi Rio so use directly: DataSet.GotoBookmark(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);

Answer (score 1):

only a single line call is needed to retrieve a value when you know the column number. The system will automatically return values from the current row, or last line clicked or double-clicked in a grid list.

```
var colidx : integer; ss : string;
```

..

```
ss := DBGrid1.Fields[colidx].AsString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution **for one selected row**:

1. Add `Data Controls > DBText` on current form.
2. Pick actual `DataSource` for `TDBText` with Object Inspector.
3. Pick necessary `DataField` in the `TDBText` with Object Inspector.
4. Get value in the code as follows: `DBText.Caption`

Answer (score 0):

this is my method to retrieve the key

```
procedure TfrmArticle.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
```

begin
op:='M';

```
with frmajtArticlee do
  begin
    Edit1.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('ID_prod').Value;
    Edit2.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('ref_art').Value;
    Edit3.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('code_barre').Value;
    Edit4.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('marque').asstring;
    Edit5.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('qts_art').Value;
    Edit6.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('designation').asstring;
    Edit7.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('prix_achats_ht').Value;
    Edit8.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('prix_vente_faciliter').Value;
    Edit9.text:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('prix_vente_cache').Value;
    val_mod:=dm.ADOQueryArticle.fieldbyname('ID_prod').asstring;
```

val_mod:string "declare it in public "

Answer (score -1):

IF YOU'RE NEED TO FIND HOW TO GET DATA OF A SELECTED ROW IN THE DBGRID, I HAD THE HINT. I USE DBGRID.SelectedField TO GET THE SELECTED FIELD AND CONVERT THE FIELD TO BE SELECTED TO BOOKMARK BY DB_GRID.SelectedField.DataSet.Bookmark
AND USE DATASET.GOTOBOOKMART TO GO TO THE SELECTED RECORD FIELD IN DBGRID DB_DATA.DataSet.GotoBookmark (DB_GRID.SelectedField.DataSet.Bookmark);

Comment: why do you use uppercase !

Comment: You do not need to do all this!  The dataset which supplies the grid's data automatically tracks the selected grid row.